# What happens when attr_accessor is within a class method?

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

So this came up to my mind and wonder what happens when some thing below is done.

```
 class Test 
   def self.abc
     attr_accessor :John 
   end
 end

 object = Test.new
 puts "before calling class method abc:  #{object.class.instance_methods(false)}"
 Test.abc
 puts "after calling class method abc:   #{object.class.instance_methods(false)}"
```

Here what I checked was, do the getter and setter methods get created in this way. And if so, are those instance methods or class methods. First I create a new object and then I view what are the instance methods of that object. After that in next line I run the `class` method `abc` and then again, I check for instance methods of `object`. At that time only I can see the two methods `John` and `John=`. How does this happen ? How come a running of a class method dynamically add methods to already created objects?. Can somebody please explain me this.

The output of the code was:

```
before calling class method abc:  []
after calling class method abc:   [:John, :John=]
```

Comment: See: Ruby Object Model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in a class method, `self` is the class itself. Therefore, the following are equivalent in what they ultimately do:

```
class Test
  def self.abc
    # `self` in this context is Test.
    # This sends the message `:attr_accessor, :john` to `Test`
    attr_accessor :john
  end
end

class Test
  # `self` in this context is Test.
  # This sends the message `:attr_accessor, :john` to `Test`
  attr_accessor :john
end
```

However, as you noted, `Test::abc` isn't executed when the class is parsed, so `attr_accessor` isn't called, and the instance methods aren't added. It is perfectly valid to do this at runtime, and in fact, is the basis of much of the metaprogramming performed in Rails.

Typically, if you expect to add accessors via a class method, you might call that class method after definition but still during class declaration:

```
class Test
  def self.abc
    attr_accessor :john
  end

  abc
end
```

This will actually run, and properly declare the accessors on the class!

As to your question:

> How come a running of a class method dynamically add methods to already created objects?

This is because instantiating a class doesn't instantiate a "snapshot" of the class at the time of instantiation - it creates an object which delegates much of its functionality (including discovery of the instance methods on it) to the class associated with it. Note that it is possible to define new methods *on an instance* which don't extend back to the class, too:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :foo
end

t1 = Test.new
t2 = Test.new

Test.send(:define_method, :bar) {}
puts t1.respond_to? :foo  # => true
puts t2.respond_to? :foo  # => true

puts t1.respond_to? :bar  # => true
puts t2.respond_to? :bar  # => true

t1.define_singleton_method(:baz) {}

puts t1.respond_to? :baz  # => true
puts t2.respond_to? :baz  # => false
```

Comment: This is a type of explanation i was looking for. Just beginning to understand meta-programming concepts. Gained good knowledge. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for enlightening us Chris, and sorry I wasn't of more help Ashan. I actually missed a very important part when reading your question, which makes my answer complete rubbish, I'll just delete it to avoid confusing other people.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note that in place of

```
object = Test.new
object.class.instance_methods(false)
```

you could simply write

```
Test.instance_methods(false)
```

so let's simplify:

```
puts "before calling class method abc:  #{Test.instance_methods(false)}"
  # (prints) []
Test.abc
puts "after calling class method abc:   #{Test.instance_methods(false)}"
  # (prints) [:John, :John=]
```

There's a short explanation of this behaviour, but also a longer one.

**Short Explanation**

```
Test.method(:attr_accessor)
  #=> #<Method: Class(Module)#attr_accessor>
```

This return value, together with the fact that

```
Test.class #=> Class
```

tells us that `attr_accessor` is an instance_method of `Class`, and therefore a method of `Test`. Let's confirm.

```
Class.instance_methods.include?(:attr_accessor)
  #=> false
```

Whoops! (You were expecting `=> true`?). That can only mean that `attr_accessor` is a protected or private instance method:

```
Class.protected_instance_methods.include?(:attr_accessor)
  #=> false

Class.private_instance_methods.include?(:attr_accessor)
  #=> true
```

Therefore

```
Class.private_instance_methods.include?(:attr_accessor)
  #=> true
```

So `attr_accessor` is simply a private instance method of `Test`'s class, `Class`, making it a private method of `Test`. The expression (from earlier)

```
Test.method(:attr_accessor)
  #=> #<Method: Class(Module)#attr_accessor>
```

also tells us that `attr_accessor` is defined in `Class`'s superclass `Module`.

```
Class.superclass
  #=> Module
Class.ancestors
  #=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
Class.instance_method(:attr_accessor).owner
  #=> Module 
Test.method(:attr_accessor).owner
  #=> Module
```

**Longer Explanation**

The method [Module#attr_accessor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) can be made available to the class `Test` in one of two ways. This is the essence of Ruby's *object model*. (I have sidestepped the place of singleton class methods.)

*1. Test inherits the method from its superclass*

```
Test.superclass
  #=> Object
Test.ancestors
  #=> [Test, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Let's see.

```
Object.method(:attr_accessor)
  #=> #<Method: Class(Module)#attr_accessor> 
Object.public_methods.include?(:attr_accessor)
  #=> false 
Object.private_methods.include?(:attr_accessor)
  #=> true
```

*2. `attr_accessor` is an instance method of `Test`'s class*

```
Test.class
  #=> Class

Class.private_instance_methods.include?(:attr_accessor)
  #=> true
```

So `Test` both inherits `attr_accessor` from its superclass and has it available as an instance method of its class. This duality is often explained with a diagram such as [this one](https://andersonleiteblog.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/model.png).

Ruby first checks `Test`'s class, `Class`, for the instance method `attr_accessor`. where it will find it. (Had she not found it there she'd then look for the method (not instance method) in the superclass.)